# Java JButton and JPanel inheriting info from array list

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to finish this project up and I'm stuck.

I need 7 classes total, app, student, group, ControlPanel, TopPanel, Mainframe, and CenterPanel.  I feel like it has something to do with my super classes but I'm not sure.

No code is to be added to the app, mainframe, or controlpanel classes.

The only changes that are allowed are in student, group, toppanel, and centerpanel.

I'm getting stuck when I try to get the students GPA from student into the CenterPanel, I got the names of the students finally but I'm still stuck on that, I guess I have to add it into the student deceleration.

However, where I'm stuck at now is I created an array list to create a group of the 4 students, and I can't figure out how to display the group and group avg in toppanel.

So far I have the following code:

### app:

```
public class app {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainFrame mjf = new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

### CenterPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4;
    student st1 = new student("Mike", "Myers");
    student st2 = new student("Michelle","Smith");
    student st3 = new student("Meg","Smith");
    student st4 = new student("Brad","Mag");


    public CenterPanel() {

        super();
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 1);
        setLayout(grid);
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        jb1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
        add(jb1);
        jb2 = new JButton(st2.getInfo());
        add(jb2);
        jb3 = new JButton(st3.getInfo());
        add(jb3);
        jb4 = new JButton(st4.getInfo());
        add(jb4);

    }

    public JButton  getJb1() {
        return jb1;
    }

    public void setJb1(JButton jb1) {
        this.jb1 = jb1;
    }

    public JButton getJb2() {
        return jb2;
    }

    public void setJb2(JButton jb2) {
        this.jb2 = jb2;
    }

    public JButton getJb3() {
        return jb3;
    }

    public void setJb3(JButton jb3) {
        this.jb3 = jb3;
    }

    public JButton getJb4() {
        return jb4;
    }

    public void setJb4(JButton jb4) {
        this.jb4 = jb4;
    }
}
```

### student:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;

public class student extends JPanel {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double randomGPA;

    public student(String pFirstName, String pLastName){
        firstName = pFirstName;
        lastName = pLastName;
        double gpa = Math.random();
        randomGPA = gpa * 5.0;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public double getRandomGPA() {
        return randomGPA;
    }

    public void setRandomGPA(double randomGPA) {
        this.randomGPA = randomGPA;
    }

        public String getInfo(){
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }

    public ComponentUI getUi() {
        return ui;
    }

    public void setUi(ComponentUI ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
    }

    public EventListenerList getListenerList() {
        return listenerList;
    }

    public void setListenerList(EventListenerList listenerList) {
        this.listenerList = listenerList;
    }

}
```

### TopPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4;
    group grp1 = new group("Semester 1 Students");

    public TopPanel() {

        super();
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        jb1 = new JButton();
        ImageIcon psu = new ImageIcon("images/psu.jpg");
        jb1.setIcon(psu);
        jb1.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb1);
        jb2 = new JButton(grp1.getGroupName());
        jb2.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb2);
        jb3 = new JButton("Group Average GPA is");
        jb3.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb3);
        jb4 = new JButton("The Groups Avg. GPA Goes Here (Extracted from the GROUP Object)");
        jb4.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb4);
    }
}
```

### group:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class group extends JPanel {

    String groupName;
    ArrayList<student> studentgrouplist;

    public group(String groupName1) {
        groupName = groupName1;
        studentgrouplist = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String groupList() {
        String info = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < studentgrouplist.size(); i++) {
            this.getStudentgrouplist().get(i);
            student temp = this.getStudentgrouplist().get(i);
            info = info + "\n" + temp.getFirstName() + " " + temp.getLastName() + ": " + temp.getRandomGPA();
        }
        return getGroupName() + info;
    }

    public double groupAvg() {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < studentgrouplist.size(); i++) {
            total = total + this.getStudentgrouplist().get(i).getRandomGPA();
        }
        return total / studentgrouplist.size();
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public ArrayList<student> getStudentgrouplist() {
        return studentgrouplist;
    }

    public void setStudentgroup(ArrayList<student> studentgrouplist) {
        this.studentgrouplist = studentgrouplist;
    }
}
```

### ControlPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    CenterPanel cp;
    TopPanel tp1;

    public ControlPanel() {
        super();
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(border);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        cp = new CenterPanel();
        tp1 = new TopPanel();
        add(tp1, "North");
        add(cp, "Center");
    }

}
```

### Mainframe:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    ControlPanel mjp;

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Assignment 05 Starter");
        mjp = new ControlPanel();
        getContentPane().add(mjp, "Center");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1200, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be extending from CenterPanel instead?

Comment: NO. Student should be a *logical* class, not a GUI component class. It should not extend from JPanel or any class that extends from a Swing component.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hmmm, my keyboard doesn't seem to like me, that or my fingers can't keep up with the brain 

Comment: @MadProgrammer: definitely the former, not the latter :/

Comment: `Student` seems to be data and should **not** extend from `JPanel`. `Student` can be visualised in any number of ways and shouldn't be constrained in this way

Comment: Welcome to SO.`Student` and `Group` are not UI components, but more like model classes, from which UI components can retrieve data. Also not that you are using `JButton`s which are meant for handling actions (clicks) as display component. It is better to use components like `JLabel` or `JTextField` for displaying short text. Please clarify how you want the group and average to show on top panel.

Comment: Is your objective to show the group and group average in the TopPanel when the user clicks the JButtons you've already added?

Answer (score 0):

Class name begin with lower class letter in Java is like writing someone's name begin with a small letter. :)

Also try to understand OOP conecept and how the data flows between classes.

You can do few changes to get your result.

**CenterPanel**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {

        JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4;
        student st1 = new student("Mike", "Myers");
        student st2 = new student("Michelle","Smith");
        student st3 = new student("Meg","Smith");
        student st4 = new student("Brad","Mag");
        Group newGroup = new Group("MY GROUP");

        public CenterPanel() {

            super();
            ArrayList<student> studentList = new Arraylist<>();
            studentList.add(st1);
            studentList.add(st2);
            studentList.add(st3);
            studentList.add(st4);
            newGroup.setStudentgroup(studentList);

            GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 1);
            setLayout(grid);
            setBackground(Color.pink);
            jb1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
            add(jb1);
            jb2 = new JButton(st2.getInfo());
            add(jb2);
            jb3 = new JButton(st3.getInfo());
            add(jb3);
            jb4 = new JButton(st4.getInfo());
            add(jb4);

        }

        public JButton  getJb1() {
            return jb1;
        }

        public void setJb1(JButton jb1) {
            this.jb1 = jb1;
        }

        public JButton getJb2() {
            return jb2;
        }

        public void setJb2(JButton jb2) {
            this.jb2 = jb2;
        }

        public JButton getJb3() {
            return jb3;
        }

        public void setJb3(JButton jb3) {
            this.jb3 = jb3;
        }

        public JButton getJb4() {
            return jb4;
        }

        public void setJb4(JButton jb4) {
            this.jb4 = jb4;
        }
    }
```

**TopPanel**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4;


    public TopPanel(group grp1) {

        super();
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        jb1 = new JButton();
        ImageIcon psu = new ImageIcon("images/psu.jpg");
        jb1.setIcon(psu);
        jb1.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb1);
        jb2 = new JButton(grp1.getGroupName());
        jb2.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb2);
        jb3 = new JButton("Group Average GPA is" + grp1.groupAvg());
        jb3.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb3);
        jb4 = new JButton("The Groups Avg. GPA Goes Here (Extracted from the GROUP Object)" + grp1.groupAvg());
        jb4.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(jb4);
    }
}
```

**ControlPanel**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    CenterPanel cp;
    TopPanel tp1;

    public ControlPanel() {
        super();
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(border);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        cp = new CenterPanel();
        tp1 = new TopPanel(cp.newGroup);
        add(tp1, "North");
        add(cp, "Center");
    }

}
```